# Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Uncaught Typeerror: Cannot set property innerHTML of null
Hello, I am taking an error with innerHTML.
I tried innerText but it did not work i search some question as like me but i did not find the solution.
These are my html and javascript files u can check them but i didn't find any proplem.

```
<body>

    <div class="quiz-container">
        <div class="quiz-header">
            <h2 id="question">Question Text</h2>

            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer">
                    <label id="a_text" for="a">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer">
                    <label id="b_text" for="b">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer">
                    <label id="c_text" for="c">Question</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" id="d" name="answer">
                    <label id="d_text" for="d">Question</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

```
const quizData = [
    {
        question: "What is the most used programming language in 2019?",
        a: "Java",
        b: "C",
        c: "Python",
        d: "JavaScript",
        correct: "d",
    },
];

const questionEl = document.getElementById('question')
const a_text = document.getElementById('a_text')
const b_text = document.getElementById('b_text')
const c_text = document.getElementById('c_text')
const d_text = document.getElementById('d_text')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')

let currentQuiz = 0;



function loadQuiz() {

    const currentQuizData = quizData[currentQuiz]
    questionEl.innerHTML = currentQuizData.question
    a_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.a
    b_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.b
    c_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.c
    d_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.d
    currentQuiz++;
}
loadQuiz();
```

Comment: Where in the HTML do you include your JavaScript file?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like `document.getElementById` is called before the browser finish to render the page.

You will need to run the code that go to the DOM just after the browser is ready.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable `questionEl` is defined as `const`; because you are trying to change the content of the variable `questionEl` inside the `loadQuiz()` method. Define the `questionEl` variable using the `let` or `var` keywords.

```js
const quizData = [
    {
        question: "What is the most used programming language in 2019?",
        a: "Java",
        b: "C",
        c: "Python",
        d: "JavaScript",
        correct: "d",
    },
];

/* The questionEl variable is defined using the "let" keyword. */
let questionEl = document.getElementById('question')
const a_text = document.getElementById('a_text')
const b_text = document.getElementById('b_text')
const c_text = document.getElementById('c_text')
const d_text = document.getElementById('d_text')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')

let currentQuiz = 0;

function loadQuiz() {
    const currentQuizData = quizData[currentQuiz]
    questionEl.innerHTML = currentQuizData.question
    a_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.a
    b_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.b
    c_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.c
    d_text.innerHTML = currentQuizData.d
    currentQuiz++;
}

loadQuiz();
```

```html
<body>
<div class="quiz-container">
    <div class="quiz-header">
        <h2 id="question">Question Text</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="a" name="answer">
                <label id="a_text" for="a">Question</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="b" name="answer">
                <label id="b_text" for="b">Question</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="c" name="answer">
                <label id="c_text" for="c">Question</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="d" name="answer">
                <label id="d_text" for="d">Question</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</body>
```